# Configuring chrome to work for selenium2.25

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am using selenium webdriver 2.25.This webdriver supports only for firefox but not Chrome.I downloaded chromedriver and added it to the ClassPath as well but my scripts are not running if i mention chrome as the browser to run.Can anyone suggest me what configuration settings am i missing ? or where i went wrong. Am using Eclipse IDE to write scripts.

Comment: ok just tel me how to make selenium run for chrome ...?

Comment: If you've just downloaded Chrome then you've downloaded the latest version which will probably have absolutely no chance at all at working with Selenium v2.25. Please update to v2.33 from the website, and let us know any exceptions you get. We cannot do anything without them.

Comment: Did you set "webdriver.chrome.driver" property?